# Setting KSOAP2 prefix on the xmlns attribute only

Tags: android, ksoap2

With **KSOAP2** I can generate this XML within a SOAP envelope:

```
<v:Envelope 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <ApplyItem xmlns="http://www.myurl.com/">
            <Item type="User" action="get" select="login_name"/>
        </ApplyItem>
     </v:Body>
 </v:Envelope>
```

**And I can get this XML by setting envelope.dotNet = false;**

```
<v:Envelope 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:ApplyItem xmlns:n0="http://www.myurl.com/">
            <n0:Item type="User" action="get" select="login_name"/>
        </n0:ApplyItem>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

**What do I need to do so I get the same XML with the 'n0' prefix only on the xmlns attribute like this**

```
<ApplyItem xmlns:n0="http://www.myurl.com/">
     <Item type="User" action="get" select="login_name" />
</ApplyItem>
```

**The code I have follows**

```
public void TestWebService() {
/*xmlVersionTag = "";
* NAMESPACE = "http://www.myurl.com/";
* SOAPaction = "ApplyItem";
* MYSERVER = "http://myServer/webservice.aspx";
* DATABASE = "dbName";
* AUTHUSER = "admin";
* AUTHPASSWORD = "pwd"; */
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SOAPaction);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.addMapping(null, "Item", new String().getClass());

SoapObject aml = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Item");
aml.addAttribute("type", "User");
aml.addAttribute("action", "get");
aml.addAttribute("select", "login_name");
request.addSoapObject(aml);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    callWS(client, MYSERVER, SOAPaction, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    Log.i("Webservice Output", response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
return;
}
```

CallWS connects using HttpClient with Http headers and posts the request data from the soap envelope and parses the response back to the envelope input.

**Here's that part of the code.**

```
public void callAras(HttpClient httpClient, 
       String url, String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope) 
       throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
if (soapAction == null) {
    soapAction = "\"\"";
 }
 byte[] requestData = createRequestData(envelope);
 String requestDump = new String(requestData);

 HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

 method.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
 method.addHeader("AUTHUSER", AUTHUSER);
 method.addHeader("AUTHPASSWORD", AUTHPASSWORD);
 method.addHeader("DATABASE", DATABASE);

 HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(requestData);
 method.setEntity(entity);
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
 InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
 parseResponse(envelope, inputStream);

 inputStream.close();
 }
```

**The fault code I receive is:**

```
SOAP-ENV:Server.TagItemIsNotFoundInRequestException
There is no tag <Item> in request.
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things 1st the request XML that worked with the web service is below. Note the 'n0' prefix was removed from the Item element.

```
<v:Envelope 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:ApplyItem xmlns:n0="http://www.myurl.com/">
            <Item type="User" action="get" select="login_name"/>
        </n0:ApplyItem>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope
```

The mistake I made was using SoapObject to define the Item element instead of using the SoapPrimitive class to define it. The code corrections are below:

```
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;

SoapPrimitive amlItem = new SoapPrimitive(NAMESPACE, "Item", "");
amlItem.addAttribute("type", "User");
amlItem.addAttribute("action", "get");
amlItem.addAttribute("select", "login_name");
request.addProperty("Item", amlItem);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Once the request worked I needed to change the cast on the response from

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

to below to deal with 'anytype' returned by KSOAP.

```
Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
```